# Spinning Two Images BEHIND an Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two images (bike wheels) that are positioned *behind* the bike frame image, but when I use Javascript to rotate the wheels, they appear to be in front of the bike frame image.

HTML

```
<div id="bike">
    <img src="frame.png">
</div>

<div id="wheel">
    <img class="spin" src="wheel.png">
    <img class="spin" id="two" src="wheel.png">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var $elie = $(".spin");
    rotate(0);
    function rotate(degree) {        
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});                      
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            rotate(++degree);
        },10);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give a z-index to the bike div

Answer (score 0):

Give a higher `z-index` value to the div with bike

```
<div id="bike" style="z-index: 2">
    <img src="frame.png">
</div>

<div id="wheel" style="z-index: 1;">    
    <img class="spin" src="wheel.png">
    <img class="spin" id="two" src="wheel.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Although, avoid using `inline-css` when you actually apply.

Comment: you are giving a wrong amount of z-index always gives bigger amount to overlap the object

Comment: @jassi9911, Please read the question. The OP wants to overlaps the wheel from bike. Which is what I am doing. So please remove your downvote. :)

Comment: oops. the things goes wrong. when i remove the downvote. it shows
`5 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited
(click on this box to dismiss)`

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following CSS:

```
   #bike{
        z-index:2;
    }

    #wheel{
        z-index:1;
    }
```

Comment: Tried adding z indexes and putting the wheels first in the HTML, both didn't work.

When I remove the Java script the bike frame is on top of the wheels.

I would set up a jsfiddle but I don't have links to the images.

Answer (score 0):

put the wheel div before bike div in the html

OR

give z-index 1 to the bike div